# Simple exercise on linear transformations - confused

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

A Linear transformation $L$ in $\mathbb R^3$ with matrix $$ L_b^b = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 0 & -2 & 2 \\ 1 & -2 & 7 \end{matrix}\right)$$ and basis $b = \{ (1,0,2), (0,2,1), (1,3,1) \}$ find $L(2,0,5)$

my first guess was $L * \left(\begin{matrix}2\\0\\5\end{matrix}\right)$ which would be $\left(\begin{matrix}27\\10\\37\end{matrix}\right)$
but I'm confused since I did not use the basis anywhere... is it given as extra info to confuse me, or did I mess up?

Comment: You messed up. To begin, write $(2, 0, 5)$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: @AlexG. thanks! somehow I always fail to see these simple first steps .. i got (2,1,0) , is the rest of what i did correct? do I now multiply L by that? that gives (2, -1, 0).

Comment: $(2, 1, 0)$ is not the correct linear combination. $2(1, 0, 2) + 1(0, 2, 1) + 0(1, 3, 1) = (2, 2, 5)$

Comment: @AlexG. My bad! redid it, it should be $(\frac{12}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{-2}{5})$ now L* that?

Comment: Yes. The vector you get should be thought of as another list of coefficients, just as $(\frac{12}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{-2}{5})$ is the list of coefficients in the linear combination for $(2, 0, 5)$. Let's call those coefficents $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$. Then you will need to use the basis again to figure out what vector is represented by this. In other words, your final answer will be $c_1 (1, 0, 2) + c_2 (0, 2, 1) + c_3 (1, 3, 1)$.

Comment: @AlexG. Oh, now I remember doing similar excercises in class! Makes sense now, thank you very much!, i got $\frac {1}{5}(2, -10, -8)$ for the coefficients, so $\frac {1}{5}(-6,-44,14)$ as my final answer.

Answer (score 1):

The set of vectors $$b = \{ (1,0,2), (0,2,1), (1,3,1) \}$$ is your basis for vector space.

You need to express the vector $(2,0,5)$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Once you have found the coordinates $ C_1, C_2, C_3$ such that     $$(2,0,5)=C_1(1,0,2)+C_2(0,2,1)+C_3(1,3,1)$$
 You  multiply your matrix

$$ L_b^b = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 0 & -2 & 2 \\ 1 & -2 & 7 \end{matrix}\right)$$

by the coordinates vector $\left(\begin{matrix}C_1\\C_2\\C_3\end{matrix}\right)
         $ to find

$$L * \left(\begin{matrix}2\\0\\5\end{matrix}\right)=$$

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 0 & -2 & 2 \\ 1 & -2 & 7 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}C_1\\C_2\\C_3\end{matrix}\right)
         $$